# What is the use of recordsPath, does it help in adding it in the production build?

Tags: webpack

There is a mention of `recordsPath` in webpack docs which talks of maintaining the state between compilation. In the current build setup that i have configured, the build first deletes the previous `build` directory created by webpack and then starts webpack compilation. So where should the `records.json` reside if it is to be used.